# Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to create a new table with a primary key that has 2 columns however I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one
> auto column and it must be defined as a key

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `score` decimal(4,3) NOT NULL,
  `raw` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`id`),
  KEY `table1_indx` (`date`,`score`,`entity_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The error message suggests that I have more than 1 auto column. Whereas I have only defined `id` as an auto-increment. Am I misinterpreting the meaning of this error?

I have defined my primary key as (date, id).

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w6mNoUQc395f3dDyaE61cW/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, but it's referring to this rule:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

> To use the AUTO_INCREMENT mechanism with an InnoDB table, an AUTO_INCREMENT column must be defined as the first or only column of some index such that it is possible to perform the equivalent of an indexed SELECT MAX(ai_col) lookup on the table to obtain the maximum column value. The index is not required to be a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE, but to avoid duplicate values in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, those index types are recommended.

You could fix the table you show by making the auto-increment the first column of the compound primary key:

```
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `date`),
...
```

Note the order of columns in the key definition doesn't have to be the same as the order of columns in the table.

Alternatively, you could define another key, even a non-unique index, with the `id` as its first column:

```
...
PRIMARY KEY (`date`, `id`),
KEY (`id`),
...
```

I can guess that you intended the auto-increment `id` to number from 1 for each distinct date. But that's not how auto-increment works in InnoDB. There is only one auto-increment counter for the table.

Comment: My intention for setting `PRIMARY KEY (`date`, `id`),` is that i want to take advantage of the performance gain by having the date in the first entry of the key as my query is always querying via the date not the id. So i guess in this case it makes sense to use the alternative solution you have provided

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make ("id") unique key not just a key whilst not using it in a partition. `Error Code: 1503. A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function (prefixed columns are not considered).` 

or does any unique field must be apart of the partitioning function?

Comment: You need to read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

Comment: "All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have."  got it thanks